# Override reset.css with browser defaults

Tags: css, css-reset

I know this might sound like a strange question but I actually need to override a CSS reset file with the browser defaults (so the other way around than normal).

So when my reset.css states

```
li{
   padding: 0;
}
```

I want to override that with the browser defaults.
Setting

```
li{
   padding: auto !important;
}
```

doesn't work though.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Browsers have different defaults - which one in particular are you targeting?

Comment: Why not remove the reset.css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default stylesheets are different from browser to browser and from version to version. You can apply the browser's default stylesheet by using the respective CSS files:

- [Mozilla's default CSS](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/layout/style/html.css)
- [WebKit's default CSS](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)
- [Opera's default CSS](http://www.iecss.com/opera-10.51.css)
- [IE9's default CSS](http://www.iecss.com/ie-9.css)

The much simpler solution might be to just remove the reset styles.

Comment: I cannot remove the reset.css but your links are very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can look up individual properties and set those as needed. This is very common in CSS but you might also use the "initial" value to do the same thing implicitly and with less effort.

For example,

```
h1 {
    color: initial; 
}
```