# text won't lay right on top of other text

Tags: html, css, text, xhtml

I have three divs. One as a container and two inside the first one is the header wish is a bit bigger, the second one is text.

Both are set to `margin: 0px;`, but still there is a 4cm gap between them. The container is also set to `margin: 0px;`; I also tried making them `<h3>` and `<p>` with `margin: 0px;` but that did not work either. What can I do?

`<div class='over'>".rubrik."</div><div class='under'>".inledning."</div><a href='post.php?id=".id."'></a></div>";`  CSS: MARGIN:0PX; I MISSED COPYING THE STARTING DIV TAG HERE

Comment: can you provide a code example?

Comment: Relevant codes please?

Comment: It won't show as code it just takes out almost all of it

Comment: Even if i indent it four spaces

Comment: did you try line-height?

Comment: no, should I put line-height: 0px;?

Comment: try with line-height;1; without px

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp here is tutorial.

Comment: then you will must provide some code so we can see whtas up

Comment: when Indent it and paste i does not show up, what should I do then?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a CSS reset with your CSS?

http://cssreset.com/

Since browsers usually have there own default styles.

[Override reset.css with browser defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272262/override-reset-css-with-browser-defaults)